# How can I click on the the first button, which is located in specific div with span class?? (using javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to navigate javascript to click on the first button, that is located in div class="important" and the div must also contain span class="something". On the page there are other divs, but not all of them contains the span class. Is there a way to do it in javascript? I tried it several times, but nothing was working.
I will be glad for any advice.
Thanks

The page code looks like:

```
...
<div class="important">
     <div>
          <span class="something">...</span>
     </div>
     <input type="button" value="Test" name="bid" class="other class">                         
</div>

<div class="important">
...
</div>
```

Comment: you question very vague and unclear. `how can I click on the first button?` what is that supposed to mean? you use your mosue and hover it over a button and click with a finger on the left mouse button... `I am trying to navigate javascript to click on the first button` why should JS click on abutton? why use an input type as button? what are youa ctually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question you want to find a button on the first `.important` div that contain `.something` class. With you markup this is how you can do it:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.important .something')[0].parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('[type="button"]');
```

Now if you want to click on it, you can add `.click()`.

Demo:

```js
function demo(btn) {
  // jsut for demo
  alert(btn.value);
};
function findBtn() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.important .something')[0].parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('[type="button"]').click();
}
```

```html
<button id="findmybtn" onclick="findBtn()">Find my button and click on it</button>
<div class="important">
    <div><span class="notsomething">notsomething</span></div>
    <input type="button" value="Test1" name="bid" class="other class" onclick="demo(this)">                         
</div>
<div class="important">
    <div><span class="something">something</span></div>
    <input type="button" value="Test2" name="bid" class="other class" onclick="demo(this)">                         
</div>
<div class="important">
    <div><span class="somethingelse">somethingelse</span></div>
    <input type="button" value="Test3" name="bid" class="other class" onclick="demo(this)">                         
</div>
<div class="important">    
    <input type="button" value="Test4" name="bid" class="other class" onclick="demo(this)">                         
</div>
<div class="important">
    <div><span class="something">something</span></div>
    <input type="button" value="Test5" name="bid" class="other class" onclick="demo(this)">                         
</div>
```

Comment: (you saved my time) ;)

Comment: No problems enjoy coding!